# Eliminar un registro de una tabla con Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal para eliminar un registro de mi tabla de la base de datos.

Esta es  la función que utilizo en mi vista ara eliminar el registro
y su respectiva ruta:

```
function eliminar(id){
     $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "tipo/eliminar/"+id,
              success: function(result){
                if(result=="0"){
                    swal("Se Ha eliminado Correctamente","","success").then((value)=>{
                        location.reload();
                    });
                }else if(result=="2"){
                    swal("Ops","Ya lo eliminaste","info");
                }else{
                    swal("Error","Se Ha Presentado Un Error","error");

                }
            }
            ,
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                swal("Error","Se Ha Presentado Un Error al eliminar el dato","error");
            }
});
}
```

--- Esta es la función en laravel ----

```
public function eliminar($id){
    $eliminar = DB::table('tipo_documento')->delete('tipo_documento_id',$id)->where('id',$id)->get();
    return $eliminar;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

**route**

```
Route::delete('/tipo/eliminar/{id}', 'TuControlador@destroy')->name('delete.docus');
```

**controller**

```
public function destroy( Request $request, $id ) {
            if ( $request->ajax() ) {
                $docu   = tipo_documento::findOrFail( $id );

                if ( $docu->delete() ) {
                    return response()->json( [
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => '¡Satisfactorio!, eliminado con éxito.',
                    ] );
                } else {
                    return response()->json( [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => '¡Error!, No se pudo eliminar.',
                    ] );
                }
            }
        }
```

**view**

```
<form action="{{ route('delete.docus',$item->id) }}" method="post">
                                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                        {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs borrar" title="Eliminar {{ $item->name }}"
                                           data-nombre="{{ $item->name }}">

                                        </a>
                                    </form>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.borrar').unbind().click(function () {
                var $button = $(this);

                var row = $(this).parents('tr');
                var $form = $(this).parents('form');
                var $url = $form.attr('action');
                var $dat = $form.serialize();       
                var $method = $form.attr('method');

                var data_nombre = $button.attr('data-nombre');


                swal({
                        title             : "¿Seguro que deseas continuar?",
                        text              : "Eliminar a: " + data_nombre + ", no podrás deshacer este paso.",
                        type              : "warning",
                        cancelButtonClass : 'btn btn-danger',
                        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                        cancelButtonColor : '#DD6B55',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        confirmButtonText : "¡Aceptar!",
                        cancelButtonText  : "Cancelar",
                        showCancelButton  : true,
                        closeOnConfirm    : false,
                        closeOnCancel     : false
                    },
                    function (isConfirm) {
                        if (isConfirm) {

                            $.ajax({
                                url     : $url,
                                type    : $method,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data    : $dat,
                                success : function ($data) {
                                    if ($data.success == true) {

                                        row.fadeOut();
                                        swal({
                                            title             : "Correcto!",
                                            text              : $data.message,
                                            timer             : 1800,
                                            showConfirmButton : false,
                                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                            type              : "success"
                                        });
                                    } else {

                                        swal({
                                            title             : "Error!",
                                            text              : $data.message,
                                            timer             : 3000,
                                            type              : "error",
                                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            swal({
                                title             : "Cancelado",
                                text              : "Tu registro está seguro :)",
                                type              : "error",
                                timer             : 2000,
                                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6'
                            });
                        }
                        $button.children('i').attr('class', 'fa fa-trash').removeAttr('disabled');
                    });

                return false;
            })
        });
```

Aclaro que en la vista usé para pasar el **id**: $item->id, esto es pensando que tengas el metodo dentro de un listado usando un **foreach**.

Espero te ayude. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que por protección y convenciones debería utilizarse el verbo DELETE y no GET en la ruta, en el peor de los casos, al menos POST, pero por ningún motivo GET.

```
Route::delete('tipo/eliminar/{id}', 'TipoController@eliminar');
```

Aunque yo prefiero utilizar Eloquent para el CRUD, teniendo en cuenta que lo haces con Query Builder, debes llamar siempre a where antes de delete:

```
DB::table('tipo_documento')->whereId($id)->delete();
```

Por cierto, no entiendo que intentas hacer pasándole un parámetro al método delete(), dicho método no acepta parámetros.